# ASP.NET Session Management DeleteExpiredSessions Looks silly?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I have a version of DeleteExpiredSessions (provided by Microsooft) which is using Cursor and storing data into temp tables. [You can find it here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973849/improved-deleteexpiredsessions-stored-procedure-in-asp-net-2-0)

And this is the source code of stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteExpiredSessions]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW 

    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE() 

    CREATE TABLE #tblExpiredSessions 
    ( 
        SessionID nvarchar(88) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    )

    INSERT #tblExpiredSessions (SessionID)
        SELECT SessionID
        FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
        WHERE Expires < @now

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE ExpiredSessionCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT SessionID FROM #tblExpiredSessions 

        DECLARE @SessionID nvarchar(88)

        OPEN ExpiredSessionCursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredSessionCursor INTO @SessionID

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionID = @SessionID AND Expires < @now
                FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredSessionCursor INTO @SessionID
            END

        CLOSE ExpiredSessionCursor

        DEALLOCATE ExpiredSessionCursor

    END 

    DROP TABLE #tblExpiredSessions

RETURN 0
```

I'm wondering why it is not simply deleting expired sessions using below query:

```
DELETE [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
WHERE Expires < GETUTCDATE()
```

Comment: why this is too broad ?, there should be some reason they have implemented this way or it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the code and thinking about potential DB load and data volume, I think the reason for this is to keep the cleanup script from causing locks that could escalate and interfere with the application. The session table would be on the critical path for every web request.

Comment: Makes sense. I overlooked that number of rows might be huge and it may cause a table lock. I'll accept your answer if I did not get a better one. Thank you!